# Handling multiple request in sequence generated by onchange event in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, httprequest, fetch-api

[onchange event search() function is calling which is sending requests to GoodReadApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwTF6.png)

[image]

I am new to Javascript and react js and I wanted to execute multiple requests in sequence as they are sending. I have tried my best but can't find best solution to the problem. anyone can tell me the way I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Why doesn't it fit you to handle each onChange event separately? I mean, you get 3 events, onChange is invoked three times...

Comment: Better describe your problem, show code, explain what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to have onChange update the field value, and to provide a 'Submit' or 'Search' button that calls the action creator that accesses GoodReads.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your opinion correctly, you need something like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputText: '',
    };
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleOnChange(event) {
    this.search(event.target.value);
    this.setState({inputText: event.target.value});
  }

  search(text) {
    //call API here....
    console.log('call api....', text);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.inputText);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```